# How to combine a record into the previous record when condition is met

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, odbc, finance, quickbooks

I am trying to create a report of items sold by customer, I have to pull from 4 different tables in QuickBooks to get the data to show in the correct manner. The invoices need to show each item except when a "Package" is sold, then just the package item number should display. This is tricky because the source data does not put the Package item number on the same line as the package price. There are no unique identifiers to roll or group the Package Item line & Package price into one.

How the report should be;

| Item Number | ---Item Description---- | Quantity | Unit Price | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T130 | Tank 130 GAL STACKABLE | 12 | 216 | 2,592 |
| T240 | TANK 240 GAL STACKABLE | 2 | 411 | 822 |
| DWT400A | 400 Double Wall Tank PKG | 2 | 1413 | 2,826 |

Unfortunately, The last line (DWT400A) I cannot find a way to merge the unit price and amount from the Package price line (in below image report).

[example of current report put into a Pivot Table -- Package price should be combined with DWT400A line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ha3Av.png)

Comment: I suspect this is probably best done in the dataset query. Can you post a sample of data from your query including everything you can join to. I suspect there must be a row/line number against each which we might be able to use.

Comment: Like Alan mentioned , it would be easier at the DB level. what verision of SQL Server are you using? Is there a way other than description to check if the line is a package line? Sample raw data would be good ..